# How to move an object use Sin& Cos in Android

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

I want my circle run graphical winding.    What should I do?
this code running diagonally.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_move);
    final MyCustomPanel view = new MyCustomPanel(this);


    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =
            new     ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    addContentView(view, params);
    findViewById(R.id.btB).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i=1;i<=1000;i++){
             x = i;
             y = i;
             view.animate().x(x).y(y).setDuration(5000).start();               
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple You have to create you Interpolator  by extending [BaseInterpolator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/BaseInterpolator.html) and provide an implementation to [getInterpolation(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeInterpolator.html#getInterpolation(float)) method.

I think you want to return just

```
public float getInterpolation(float input) {
       return (float)(Math.cos((input) * Math.PI)
       }
```

Comment: I tried this and it's working perfectly fine. I used the code   DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                TranslateAnimation translation = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0F, 0f, metrics.widthPixels);
                translation.setStartOffset(500);
                translation.setDuration(2000);
                translation.setFillAfter(true);
                translation.setInterpolator(new SinInterpolator());
                animView.startAnimation(translation);

Comment: hi.  Neeraj Kumar  http://prntscr.com/86oueb and this http://prntscr.com/86ousc but not active